# How to optimise neo4j cypher query for high size graph?

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

I wrote this query to find possible paths between two nodes. However, when I try to use more than 3 steps, it can't finish the job. Graph that I used contains more than 4mil nodes with 49mil relations.

```
match (src:T047 {CUI:"C0030920"}), 
      (trg:T059 {CUI:"C1294944"}),
      p = (src)-[*..3]-(trg)
where 
      all(relI in relationships(p) 
      where type(relI) in ["RO","CHD","PAR","RB","RL","RO","SIB","RU","SY"])
and
      all(nodeI in nodes(p)
      where labels(nodeI) in ["T004", "T005", "T007", "T016", "T017", "T018", "T019", "T020",
            "T021", "T022", "T023", "T024", "T025", "T026", "T028", "T029", "T030", "T031", "T032", 
            "T033", "T034", "T037", "T038", "T039", "T040", "T041", "T042", "T043", "T045", "T046",
            "T047", "T048", "T049", "T053", "T054", "T055", "T056", "T057", "T059", "T060", "T061", 
            "T074", "T080", "T081", "T098", "T099", "T100", "T101", "T103", "T109", "T114", "T116", 
            "T121", "T123", "T125", "T126", "T127", "T129", "T131", "T168", "T184", "T190", "T191", 
            "T195", "T196", "T197", "T200", "T201"])
return p
```

Here is plan for this query:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNi4A.jpg

Is there any possible ways to optimise this query or at least find estimation time?

Comment: Please run an EXPLAIN of the query and add the query plan to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your query plan shows you aren't using indexes, so it's using a NodeByLabelScan for :T059 nodes and running a filter on all of them to find those with the property in question. The `src` node also isn't using an index lookup, instead the results of the variable-length expand are filtered for the label and property.

You will need indexes on these to help improve performance. Indexes on `:T047(CUI)` and `:T059(CUI)` are the ones you need here. Make sure you have this first.

Also, to force index lookup (as opposed to a var-length-expand and filter, which would be more expensive) you can provide index hints to the planner.

We can also adjust the list predicate for labels on nodes in the path such that they will be filtered during expansion instead of afterward.

```
WITH ["T004", "T005", "T007", "T016", "T017", "T018", "T019", "T020", "T021", "T022", "T023", "T024", "T025", "T026", "T028", "T029", "T030", "T031", "T032", "T033", "T034", "T037", "T038", "T039", "T040", "T041", "T042", "T043", "T045", "T046", "T047", "T048", "T049", "T053", "T054", "T055", "T056", "T057", "T059", "T060", "T061", "T074", "T080", "T081", "T098", "T099", "T100", "T101", "T103", "T109", "T114", "T116", "T121", "T123", "T125", "T126", "T127", "T129", "T131", "T168", "T184", "T190", "T191", "T195", "T196", "T197", "T200", "T201"] as allowedLabels
MATCH (src:T047 {CUI:"C0030920"}), 
      (trg:T059 {CUI:"C1294944"})
USING INDEX src:T047(CUI)
USING INDEX trg:T059(CUI)
MATCH p = (src)-[*..3]-(trg)
WHERE 
      all(relI in relationships(p) WHERE type(relI) in ["RO","CHD","PAR","RB","RL","RO","SIB","RU","SY"])
    AND all(node IN nodes(p) WHERE labels(node)[0] IN allowedLabels)
RETURN p
```

This also assumes that all the nodes here only have one possible label, and not multiple. If they can have multiple labels, then we may need to restructure the query.

Comment: I'm really sorry about my english. Let me explain my case. I work with ULMS Metathesaurus. My goal is to find stable patterns between groups (T[001-127]). I have data that describes relations that are not native implemented in UMLS. So, i start serchin with two approwed entities. I suppose, that there is some stable paths, that can be used as patterns. This patterns i want to use as unload algorithms.

Comment: Your advice is really helpful, but it doesn't work on jump count over 3. On 3 jumps there is a good performance improve.

Comment: It would help to know how many paths are returned on jump counts over 3. Change your RETURN to `RETURN count(p)`, and maybe provide a table with the upper bound you're using along with the returned count of paths, as well as a PROFILE plan of the run. That should show if this is an issue of a high number of paths being filtered or something else.